# x86 ASM: how return to different code segment is implemented?

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm getting acquainted with [PCASM](http://pacman128.github.io/static/pcasm-book.pdf) book, and i don't understand one thing (which may be just my misunderstanding, i'm still new to low-level programming). It is told that c calling convention is something like

- push arguments onto stack
- use `call` instruction to call the subroutine, which, among other things, will push return address on stack
- refer to arguments adding constant offset to `ESP`
- call `ret` when you done which will pop return address (then optionally pop arguments if you wish) and use it to jump back to the calling code

So far so good, but examples tell that return code is simply four bytes on the stack. That allows to jump anywhere on current code segment, but what if subroutine has to return to another segment? If code segment has to be pushed on the stack the same way as return address, how should one refer to arguments in subroutine (because they will have different offset on near and far return)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `retf` instruction performs a "long return" which includes a segment and offset.

Comment: In the unlikely case i'll be writing something in ASM that may be used virtually anywhere (whenever i'm not sure the returning code is in the same segment), i should just use `retf` by default?

Comment: Absolutely not. It can only be used when the function was called via an accompanying "long call". The number of bytes pushed/popped is different.

Comment: @Etki You are programming in protected mode (PM) judging by the document you linked. You'll never need to do a far call/return because no OS has ever implemented more than one public user-mode code segment - you are not supposed to change segment. All OSes implement the flat model where a single segment covers all the 32-bit address space - no need for other segments (isolation is achieved through paging). Further far returns are more involved in PM if they require an inter-privilege transfer and are only possible to less privileged segments. The Intel manuals cover all this up.

Comment: Thanks @MargaretBloom, you've added a lot of good information to my terse answer.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart thank you, i'm having trouble times changing my mental model